# How can I cut connected graph lines?

Tags: matplotlib

[image]
[image]

I'm gonna draw a graph that shows Time per speed.
But the lines are connect each other at the end to start like picture.
How can i cut connected graph lines??

Answer (score 0):

This bug is likely because the data you're plotting on the x-axis isn't sorted and your data for the y-axis isn't paired to the sorted `x` data.

To illustrate this, consider trying to plot `y=x^2`

```
x = np.array([1,3,5,6,2,4,8,7])
y = np.array([1,9,25,36,4,16,64,49])

plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Python is plotting the points according to their index in the array and connecting the lines between consecutive points. To get the data in the correct order, you can `np.argsort`, which sorts the elements in an array and returns the indices of the sorted elements.

```
xnew = x[np.argsort(x)]
ynew = y[np.argsort(x)]

plt.plot(xnew, ynew)
```

[image]

It's important to note that we want to sort the `y` values according to their `x` values, which is why `np.sort` isn't used.

For your dataset, I would create a variable for the sorted indices

```
indx = np.argsort(mean_spd_per_time_array[:, 0])
```

Then create new `x` and `y` variables to plot

```
# Sort the data according to x values
x = mean_spd_per_time_array[:, 0][indx]
y = mean_spd_per_time_array[:, 1][indx]
```

Comment: _It's important to note that we want to sort the `y` values according to their `x` values [...]_. Then `ynew = y[np.argsort(y)]` should be `ynew = y[np.argsort(x)]`, I guess?